# Centering html elements

Tags: css

I am making an ASP.NET web control. In a table, how can I center a button?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to center an inline element set the container to:

```
text-align:center; eg:
<div style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" value="Center Me!"></div>
```

If you want to center a block level element set it to:

```
margin:auto; eg:
<div style="margin:auto;">Im in the middle</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to put

```
<td align="center">
  --content here--
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is very simple ..**

```
 <div>
         //your html code ..
         <table>
                 //data inside the table ..
                 <button align="center"> Click here </button>        
         </table> 
    </div>
```